# Java parallax scrolling

Tags: java, scroll, parallax, graphics2d

So, I have a really weird bug that I can't for the life of me figure out.  I've implemented a parallax scrolling background of stars, each layer moving at a percent of the camera's speed (the percent is passed in the constructor to the subclass Layer).  But, when I change that percent it doesn't seem to slow down in relation to the camera, just in relation to the other layers.  I mean, I am moving it at 0.000000001d per tick (which happens 30/s), yet it appears to go just as fast as one moving at 0.01d per tick.  What gives?  Am I overlooking something obvious?

BTW, this is just a prototype (the end result will have a few more layers and nebula and such), so no need to tell me how I should be using arrays for layers or anything like that.  I know.

Code:

```
public class Background {


private final Layer bg1 = new Layer(0.01d);
private final Layer bg2 = new Layer(0.1d);
private final Layer bg3 = new Layer(0.4d);
private final Layer bg4 = new Layer(1d);

protected int size;

private final ViewPort SviewPort;

/**
 * constructor of Background - make sure to call init() after all other constructors are complete
 * @param viewPort a viewport from which to take starting dimensions
 */
public Background(ViewPort viewPort) {
    this.SviewPort = viewPort;


    size = SviewPort.width + 100;
    if(size < SviewPort.height) size = SviewPort.height + 100;

    bg1.bg = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    bg2.bg = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    bg3.bg = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    bg4.bg = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

    int numStars = (int) Math.round(Math.pow(size/44, 2));

    Graphics2D g = bg1.createGraphics();
    for(int i = 0; i <= numStars; i++) {
        g.drawRect(Util.getRandomInt(size), Util.getRandomInt(size), 0, 0);
    }

    g = bg2.createGraphics();
    for(int i = 0; i <= numStars; i++) {
        g.drawRect(Util.getRandomInt(size), Util.getRandomInt(size), 0, 0);
    }

    g = bg3.createGraphics();
    for(int i = 0; i <= numStars; i++) {
        g.drawRect(Util.getRandomInt(size), Util.getRandomInt(size), 0, 0);
    }

    g = bg4.createGraphics();
    for(int i = 0; i <= numStars; i++) {
        g.drawRect(Util.getRandomInt(size), Util.getRandomInt(size), 1, 1);
    }


}
/**
 * init values
 */
public void init() {
    bg1.init();
    bg2.init();
    bg3.init();
    bg4.init();
}
/**
 * called to paint background
 * @param g graphics object
 * @param view viewport object
 */
public void paint(Graphics2D g, ViewPort view) {

    bg1.draw(g, view);
    bg2.draw(g, view);
    bg3.draw(g, view);
    bg4.draw(g, view);

}


private class Layer implements Tickable {

    protected BufferedImage bg;
    protected double speed;

    private double currentX,currentY;

    Layer(double speed) {
        //if(speed > 1) speed = 1;
        //else if(speed < 0) speed = 0;

        this.speed = speed;


    }


    public void init() {
        Game.add(this);
    }

    public Graphics2D createGraphics() {
        return bg.createGraphics();
    }
    /**
     * gets called to draw the layer
     * @param g graphics object
     * @param view window, or viewport object
     */
    public void draw(Graphics2D g, ViewPort view) {

        double cx = view.getCenterX();
        double cy = view.getCenterY();


        //modify currentX and currentY to reflect centerpoint:
        //'jump' the background to keep the ship centered on it while not appearing to move the background.

        int div = size/2;
        System.out.println(size);
        if(cx > currentX + div) currentX += size;
        else if(cx < currentX - div) currentX -= size;

        if(cy > currentY + div) currentY += size;
        else if(cy < currentY - div) currentY -= size;



        //drawing the background

        cx = view.x;
        cy = view.y;

        g.drawImage(bg, Util.r(currentX - size - cx), Util.r(currentY - size - cy), null);
        g.drawImage(bg, Util.r(currentX - cx),        Util.r(currentY - size - cy), null);
        g.drawImage(bg, Util.r(currentX - size - cx), Util.r(currentY - cy), null);
        g.drawImage(bg, Util.r(currentX - cx),        Util.r(currentY - cy), null);

    }
    /**
     * gets called every 'tick' of game time
     */
    @Override
    public void tick() {
        PlayerShip ship = Game.getShip();

        double deltaX = -ship.deltaX;
        double deltaY = -ship.deltaY;

        currentX += deltaX*speed;
        currentY += deltaY*speed;

        //debug
        System.out.print("dX: " + deltaX + "*" + speed + "=" + deltaX*speed + "  |  ");
        System.out.println("dY: " + deltaY + "*" + speed + "=" + deltaY*speed);
    }



}

}
```